# Is every integrable function on the real line with compact support also square integrable?

Tags: harmonic-analysis

I wonder that whether every integrable function on the real line with compact support is also square integrable ? In other words, is $L^1_c(\mathbb R)\subseteq L^2(\mathbb R)$ holds true? Thanks in advance for any hints.

Comment: If $f\in L^2[a,b]$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb R$, then $f\in L^1[a,b]$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 8):

Consider $x \mapsto 1/ \sqrt x$

Comment: or any function $x^a$ for $-1\lt a\le-\frac12$. (+1)

Comment: How does this function have compact support?

Comment: @user2357112 I left the details to the OP.